# Деструкторы в php - какой в них смысл?

Tags: php

Начал изучение магических методов PHP. С большинством все понятно. Но вот `__destruct()`, я не могу понять практическое применение его именно в PHP. В каких случаях он нужен вообще? Время жизни объектов же крайне не большое. Какая практическая польза?

Всем спасибо за ответы. Конкретно определить самый правильный не могу. Много интересных вещей написано в комментариях.

Comment: Может быть и большое, например несколько лет.

Comment: это каким образом?

Comment: Ну например сервер запустили, и не трогают.

Comment: а какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Типа работает - не трогай

Comment: В теории можно писать демоны на php. Тогда lifetime скрипта будет измеряться в днях. Зачем? Потому что удобный и знакомый ЯП.

Comment: используя деструкторы, можно писать более прозрачный код. К примеру, в конструкторе файл открывается, в деструкторе - закрывается. Таким образом, внутри других методов не нужно думать о том, что нужно закрыть файл.

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис, а что, в PHP какие-то особые деструкторы, принципиально отличающиеся от деструкторов в других языках? И при чём тут время жизни объекта?

Comment: пару примеров увидел, интересно

Comment: @Pink Tux, такие же самые просто мне не ясна практическая сторона, в целом время жизни объектов это момент пока загружается страница, тоесть всего несколько секунд, и в моем понимании деструкторы ну хоть как-то нужны онли на хайлоадах или каких-то очень серьездных проектах...

Comment: php это не только генерация страниц, на нем можно писать практически все (если не упрется в быстродействие). К тому же, даже для сервера, есть сценарии, когда скрипт запускается и обрабатывает клиентов без перезапуска (как в node.js). Или например посмотрите http://socketo.me/ (обрабатывает соединения вебсокетов).

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис, даже если ограничить php созданием страниц (что далеко не так), то и здесь можно успеть столько наворотить, что руками наводить порядок после отработки скрипта - не лучшая идея. Тем более если мест разрушения объекта может быть больше одного.

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис Почитайте так же про FastCGI, при использовании этой технологии никто не мешает скрипту php запустится в момент прихода первого клиента (или вместе с web-сервером) и не завершаться никогда, продолжая обрабатывать поступающие запросы (что обычно гораздо быстрее). Вы ориентируетесь на то, что пришел запрос, запустился скрипт, послал ответ, завершился. Это слишком узкий взгляд на язык. В таком режиме он часто используется, но далеко не всегда.

Comment: Случай из практики. У нас есть демон на php, в котором один объект N использует дескриптор подключения к БД (который то же является объектом). И у нас были постоянные проблемы с большим количеством соединений к БД. Оказалось, что демон при проблемах с соединением убивает объект N и снова пересоздает его. Из-за особенностей php ссылка на дескриптор подключения удалялась не сразу. И именно в деструкторе объекта N прописали принудительное удаление ссылки на объект. В результате нагрузка на сервер БД упала практически до нуля.

Comment: Так же замечу, что понятие деструкторов плотно связано с понятием ссылок в php. Крайне рекомендую ознамиться с разделом "Сборщик мусора" http://php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.php

Comment: Отличный пример. Спасибо. И за ссылку тоже, это интересно

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, почитаю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Деструктор позволяет вашим объектам предоставлять гарантии по управлению ресурсами. В деструкторе вы можете написать логику, которая так или иначе - во время сборки мусора или при выключении VM - будет выполнена, и не оставит ваше приложение в неконсистентном состоянии. Сама логика может быть произвольной - чаще всего в пример приводят файл, который необходимо закрыть. Клиентский код может забыть это сделать, и тогда работу за него произведет деструктор. В качестве более интересного примера можно привести ссылочную систему: например, в системе есть кэш с коротким временем жизни, который самоуничтожается после того, как последний клиент отключился. В этом случае в деструкторе клиента такого кэша должна выполняться логика дерегистрации, чтобы кэш вовремя смог освободить оперативную память.

При этом все нельзя забывать, что машина, на которой выполняется код, ненадежна и может упасть прямо посередине какой-либо транзакции - в этом случае код в деструкторе не выполнится.

Comment: тобишь основная надобность это обезопасить на случай краха сервера?

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис нет, это наоборот вас не спасет в случае краха сервера. Это подхват ответственности с клиентского кода (который может забыть закрыть/удалить временный файл, произвести дерегистрацию или что-то еще) на уровне текущего класса.

Comment: @Etki какого клиентского кода, сервер упал - всё упало он ничего не отдаёт больше. Упал скрипт ok ресурсы освободились(скрипта же нет)...

Comment: @Naumov клиентский код - это тот, который использует рассматриваемый код. Вы можете написать какой-то сложный парсер, использующий файл в качестве временного хранилища (чтобы не грузить оперативу). В том случае, если клиентский код не вызвал `.close()`, его может вызвать деструктор, чтобы этот временный файл не был оставлен на диске. Падения сервера за пределами контекста деструкторов и самими деструкторами не расматриваются; я про то, что гарантии, предоставляемые деструктором, не бесконечны.

Comment: @Etki Как пример фаил плох, вы сравниваете php и java, я понимаю что язык это всего лишь инструмент. Но есть и отличия, в php есть примитивный сборщик мусора, который автоматом и уничтожает ссылки. При завершение скрипта всё что было занято освобождаеться. Ну и php интерпретируеться а не выполняеться в виртуальной машине.

Comment: @Naumov 1) Вы вообще не поняли пример про кэш. Мне не нужно ждать, пока на него не останется физических ссылок, мне нужно вызвать unset в тот момент, когда не останется клиентов, а сама переменная/поле может и дальше существовать. При чем тут джава, вообще не понял. 2) да [неужто](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3380585/2908793)

Comment: @Etki Там идёт обсуждение софта надстройки типо opcache и т.д. Жава же компилируеться в байт код который уже выполняеться `JVM` виртуальной жава машиной(прослойка обеспечивающаю кросплатформеность приложений java), php же интерпритируеться интерпритатором и результат отдаёться сервером. Это две разные вещи виртуальная машина и интерпритатор.

Comment: @Naumov еще раз: PHP тоже компилируется в аналог байт-кода. И внутри тоже виртуальная машина, принимающая платформонезависимый байткод и транслирующая его в платформозависимый машинный код.

Answer (score 2):

деструктор вызываеться при завершение скрипта и при освобождение ссылок т.е. если у нас есть `myClass` с содержимым

```
class myClass {
   public function __construct() 
   {
       echo 'construct';
   }

   public function __destruct()
   { 
       echo 'destruct';
   }
}
```

то при выполнение

```
$test = new myClass();
unset($test); //destruct
$test = null; //destruct
exit(); // destruct
```

Но если смотреть на web программирование. то при завершение скрипта все ресурсы которорые были задействованы освобождаються автоматически(по этому использование сдесь его не целесообразно).

Если смотреть на 'демоны' на php. Он будет срабатывать на `unset($object)`, но тут тоже вопрос будет ли этот `unset` или его не будет, а реализованно всё это будет как register т.е. нужин ли нам instance объекта постоянно и неизменно, в конце концов нужны ли объекты вообще...

Answer (score 0):

Я когда-то писал класс, который записывает в базу данных активность пользователя, обновляет время последнего посещения, браузер и т.д.

Так вот в конструкторе я указывал мне нужные переменные, базы например. А в деструкторе, чтобы не писать одну строчку где-либо в коде, обновлял всю инфу в базе. Может быть это глупо, не знаю. Ну в общем достойное придумать для деструктора что-то можно)

Comment: В деструкторы не рекомендуется пихать "логику". Они должны использоваться в основном для освобождения ресурсов, которые использует экземпляр класса